# Social media buttons not working in Firefox

Tags: facebook, firefox, facebook-like

I've added some Social media buttons to my site which works fine in Chrome and IE. But on Firefox none of the social media buttons displays.

Chrome:
http://gyazo.com/6d3d01ea308c53819e207a91399c505c

Firefox:
http://gyazo.com/6db9a366cdad5f52ba9d7efb1d079b21

Code:
http://pastebin.com/KMRix3aL

Sorry about the code, every time i try to add code to the thread it gives me an error.

Comment: Hmm, it was because of some addon in Firefox, I will try to see which one caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was an addon in Firefox. The addon was 'avast! Online Security 9.0.2006.53' I will report this to avast! and see what happends.